# FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag error for sharing in custom spinner

Tags: android

i want to use share button in custom spinner

it's my code:

```
btnShareCS_One.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Share
        // Share Selected Item In Cell-Phone
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = txtTitleCS_One.getText().toString() + ": " + edtContentCS_One.getText().toString();
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, txtTitleCS_One.getText().toString());
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
// sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
// sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }
});
```

But Not Work
Error:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

How To Fix It?

my custom spinner work correctly, code work correctly but not in custom spinner

i tried to use:

```
                getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), "Share via"));
```

so it don't works too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it

```
            // Share Selected Item In Cell-Phone
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = note.title + ":" + "\n" + note.detail;
            // sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, note.title + ":");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            G.currentActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "اشتراک با..."));
```

And
    G.currentActivity

```
G
```

Is Global Class Extends Application And

```
currentActivity
```

is static Variable From Activity

Answer (score 2):

You just have to uncomment the line

`sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

You are having this problem because you're calling the method **startActivity()** from outside of an Activity without the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

Comment: can i have your mail?  i have been blocked to ask question, please

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you used Intent from non Activity class then there is need to add below mentioned line to convey that we are calling Activity from Non Activity

**sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);**

Thanks

Comment: it done. i used G.currentActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via")); so G is class extends Application, that's Global Class Run when app running, curentActivity is static variable so set in onCreate of activity

Comment: hello @user3320557 can i have your mail? i have been blocked to ask question! i have some problems but there is no one to help me

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");

            String textMessage = "Text Of Message";
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textMessage);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```