# Starting a activity from IntentService

Tags: java, android, service, share, intentfilter

It is already answered many times in past on SO :

1. [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag error for sharing in custom spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302036/flag-activity-new-task-flag-error-for-sharing-in-custom-spinner)

This answer is not working anymore over API level 23 and above. previous answers are obsolete now.

I also referred official https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send

**What is scene :**

I have a audio file to share with capable apps, which support `ACTION_SEND`. I am trying this from a `intentService`

**What i am trying since more than a hour now :**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(PATH);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, uri);
share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
this.getApplicationContext().startActivity(share);
```

> Exception : Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity 
>   context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
>
> After many times of changing code, it started working with Gmail but
>   then i got :  Exception : android.os.FileUriExposedException:
>   file:///storage/emulated/0/test.mp3 exposed beyond app through
>   Intent.getData()

Then i given read permission like :

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("audio/*");
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(PATH)));

if ( shareIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null )
{
     startActivity(shareIntent);
}
else
{
     Log.d("SEND :", "shareAction: NO APP \n");
}
```

> Exception : Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity 
>   context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.

**What my concerns are :**

1. Is android not smart enough which is not finding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` ?
2. Does android want me to open my apps activity first and then i should `startactivity` from activity only?
3. Already after the things are settled, a notifier class has provided a notification, with intentservice to handle SHARE or CANCEL buttons on notification as options, Now should i again create new activity which will again get these intent extras which are coming from several classes and long distance, should android want to burden developer to just keep moving data for multiple times for just single task?
4. What actually it wants?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to start it from a background service?

Comment: Also see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts), even if you're using a foreground service.

Comment: @JakeB, Yes i do, But its a intentservice associated with notification without pendingintent rather 2 action buttons, but this pointer must be enough..

Comment: @greeble31, I targeting 29 but it is causing exception since 23 onwards upto 29, Android 10 (API level 29) and higher place restrictions i read the link